# How to detect release/snapshot versioning of maven artifact?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I want to deploy bunch of maven artifacts(`war`,`jar`,`pom`) to a remote repository(`artifactory`) and using maven command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
  -Dversion=<version> \
  -Dpackaging=<type-of-packaging> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

we have to specify which repository(either `release` or `snapshot`) and url should be use.
I want to know, is there a way to specify the maven versioning?
for example the `ant-contrib:ant-contrib:1.0b2` artifact is for snapshot.

Comment: Why you are using command ? Are these third party jar or internal?

Comment: They are jar files not on maven repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how are you are managing the project.version in pom.xml. It should end with SNAPSHOT for snapshots mvn deploy command should deploy to snapshot.

If your  project.version in pom.xml SNAPSHOT as suffix --> deploy to snapshotRepository.

If project.version does not have SNAPSHOT as suffix in pom.xml  --> deploy to release repository.